# find max-min values for one column based on another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, data-analysis

I have a dataset that looks like this.

```
datetime                    id
2020-01-22 11:57:09.286 UTC 5
2020-01-22 11:57:02.303 UTC 6
2020-01-22 11:59:02.303 UTC 5
```

Ids are not unique and give different datetime values. Let's say:

duration = max(datetime)-min(datetime).

I want to count the ids for what the duration max(datetime)-min(datetime) is less than 2 seconds. So, for example I will output:

```
count = 1
```

because of id 5. Then, I want to create a new dataset which contains only those rows with the min(datetime) value for each of the unique ids. So, the new dataset will contain the first row but not the third. The final data set should not have any duplicate ids.

```
datetime                    id
2020-01-22 11:57:09.286 UTC 5
2020-01-22 11:57:02.303 UTC 6
```

How can I do any of these?

P.S: The dataset I provided might not be a good example since the condition is 2 seconds but here it's in minutes

Comment: You should post the original dataframe based on which you derive the excepted output. Reverse engineering wouldnt be possible

Comment: that's the original dataframe, I need output from this @anky

Comment: Could you see the edit? @anky

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this? :

```
df.datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime)
c = 0
def count(x):
    global c
    x = x.sort_values('datetime')
    if len(x) > 1:
        diff = (x.iloc[-1]['datetime'] - x.iloc[0]['datetime'])
        if diff < timedelta(seconds=2):
            c += 1
            return x.head(1)

new_df = df.groupby('id').apply(count).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Now, if you print `c` it'll show the count which is 1 for this case and `new_df` will hold the final dataframe.

Comment: Could you explain this? Where do I apply the <2 seconds filter?

Comment: It gives me ```TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'``` for now. Also, could you explain what ```x.iloc[-1]['datetime'] - x.iloc[0]['datetime']``` is doing?

Comment: you need to convert dtype of datetime column

Comment: And are you sure you want the diff <2 sec?  because if we see rows 1 and 3 the time diff is less than 2 mins 1:53 sec approx not less than 2 sec? In this code, I'm checking if the diff is >2 sec. Please, change the condition acc to your requriement.

Comment: Yup, I need the 2 second condition but the data I provided is not reflecting that. However, I just realized that in the final dataset, I only want to include min date time values of sessionId <= 2 seconds. Which means that the count and number of rows for the new dataset should be the same. Which is not the case currently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231863/discussion-between-nk03-and-jbd).